# AWK: Assign a variable to each field

Tags: arrays, variables, unix, awk

I need to assign a variable to each field, to later generate HTML.
My data file looks like this:

```
field1;field2;field3                # << RECORD 1
this;is;second;record               # << RECORD 2
```

Is there a way to generate an array for each record, based on the record number? Like arrayNR, so:

```
array1[0] = "field1"; array1[1] = "field2"; 
     ^ record number
array2[0] = "this"; array2[1] = "is"; array2[2] = "second"; array2[3] = "record"
     ^ record number
```

Comment: If you need to use standard Awk, would it not make sense to assign each line to the array, and split it again when you need it? Or just build an associative array with keys like "2:3" to identify the third value on the second line. If yu need this, I can post an answer with details, but the solution I would recommend is to switch away from Awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Gnu awk multidimensional arrays and `split`, for example:

```
$ awk '{array[NR][1]; split($0,array[NR],";"); for(i in array[NR]) print array[NR][i]}' file

{
    array[NR][1]               # initiate array
    split($0,array[NR],";")    # split to array
        for(i in array[NR])    # iterate thru all array elements
            print array[NR][i] # output array value
}
```

Comment: +1, for the `array[NR][1]` trick to initialize the array before the split command. Otherwise split complains that `second argument is not an array`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can have multidimensional arrays:

```
gawk -F\; '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][i]=$i}END {for(i in a) for (j in a[i]) print a[i][j]}' file
```

With other awks you can use:

```
awk -F\; '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR,i]=$i}END {for(i in a) {split(i,b,SUBSEP); print a[b[1],b[2]]}}' file
```